# Merging role defaults with runtime vars

Tags: ansible

Let's say I've got a role `org.foo` with the following files:

**`defaults/main.yml`**:

```
service_conf:
  includes:
    - "thing.conf"
  main:
    host: "foo.example.com"
    port: 1234
    # plus a whole bunch more
```

**`templates/service.conf.j2`**:

```
{% for value in service_conf.includes %}
include '{{ value }}'
{% endfor %}

{% for key,value in service_conf.main.iteritems() %}
{{ key }} = '{{ value }}'
{% endfor %}
```

and at some point in a task I'd like to:

1. Append an item to `service_conf.includes`
2. Add or modify an entry in `service_conf.main`

How would I do this?

I've tried `set_fact` like below, but it ends up replacing the default values rather than modifying them.

```
- name: adjust config
  set_fact:
    service_conf:
      main:
        host: 'app.domain.com'
        port: '5678'
        tls: 'yes'
  when: condition = 'happened'
```